# get the type parameter for a Scala type

Tags: scala

Using `TypeTag` I've been able to retrieve the type information about my polymorphic type.

```
scala> paramInfo(List(1,2)).tpe
res18: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = List[Int]
```

Now I want to retrieve the `Int.type`, but apparently I'm unable to do so.

```
scala> paramInfo(List(1,2)).tpe.typeParams
res19: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List()
```

Is what I want to do possible, and if it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
paramInfo(List(1,2)).tpe match {
  case TypeRef(_, _, params) => params
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the signature of `paramInfo` like that:

```
def paramInfo[T](x: List[T])(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): TypeTag[T] = tag
```